# How can I test if an item is anchored?

Tags: qml

What is the proper way to test if an item has been anchored?  For example, take the left side, I have tried:

```
property bool isAnchored: parent.anchors.left != undefined
```

But that does not seem to work?  I also tried:

```
    property bool isAnchored: !!parent.anchors.left
```

which also does not seem to work, I also tried:

```
    property bool isAnchored: parent.anchors.left ? true : false
```

Any other ideas?  There has to be a way to check if an item is anchored but I can not find it?

Comment: `anchors.left` is a class of type `QQuickAnchorLine` so it cannot be `undefined`. It rather is _unassigned_. Check the [source](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickanchors_p_p.h) may be you will find a solution. Btw, for what you need to test the anchor property?

Comment: I want to display an affordance whenever an item/rectangle is not anchored to another object (indicating it can be freely moved).  So basically I am trying to test if the object is anchored and then setting another objects visibility accordingly.

The QQuickAnchorLine only seems to have the == operator overloaded (and it is only used to compare two QQuickAnchorLine).  The QQuickAnchors class only seems to expose the QQuickAnchorLine objects and does not seem to have a way to query the flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't see any way to do it using the provided/exposed properties.  The only thing that determines a valid anchor is the `Anchors` [flag type](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickanchors_p.h.html#QQuickAnchors::Anchor) which is defined in the `QQuickAnchorLine::anchorLine` [member](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickanchors_p_p.h.html#QQuickAnchorLine::anchorLine), but that's not exposed to QML anywhere (eg. `anchors.left.anchorLine` is always `undefined`). Or in the public C++ API for that matter. The actual `QQuickAnchorLine`s attached to each object are always valid/non-null, as you've discovered.

I think you will need to implement your own flags in whatever routine(s) which set or remove the anchors in your code (I assume that has to be determined somewhere).  That is, whenever an anchor changes, set a custom property value.  There are also the anchor change signals (`leftChanged()` etc.) which could be `connect`ed to.

Alternatively, you could re-implement your own attached Anchors object in C++ and track whatever properties you want (basically same as the above suggestion but centralized in a C++ class).  [Here is a good example](http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-quick-ui-elements/blob/master/QQuickExtraAnchors.cpp) (I think, not my code) of defining your own anchors lines using a custom attached object. With something like this it would be pretty easy to track/query what is anchored to what.